# Checking if session exists doesn't work

Tags: php, session

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!-- ERA DSIGN DESIGN BY SHOWTIME -->
<!-- COPYRIGHT 2014 CristianD DESIGN -->
<head>
<title>eRa Design</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
        <a href="index.html"><div class="item">Home</div></a>
        <a href="team.html"><div class="item">The Team</div></a>
        <a href="portofolio.html"><div class="item">Portofolio</div></a>
        <a href="recruitment.html"><div class="item">Recruitment</div></a>
        <a href="store.php"><div class="item">Design Store</div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="article">
<?php
if($_SESSION['admin']):
?>
<h2>Test</h2>
<?php
else:
?>
<form action="view.php" method="post">
<input type="password" name="password" class="sharp">
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Login">
</form>
<?php
if($_POST['password'] == 'luridpls')
$_SESSION['admin'] = 'logged';
else echo "Wrong Password!";
endif;
?>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        (C) eRa Design - 2014<br>
        <em>Designed by ShowTime</em>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The code above is supposed to be a secure page, which will use sessions. The problem is when the login is processed, it checks wether the password is good or not, but doesn't set the session (that or my `if` condition is broken).

Any ideas ? :/

Comment: Also, it's a good practice to put session_start on top of everything that is sent out to requesting client. In your case <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: It's not a good practice, it is an essential condition to manage session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php session_start(); has to be invoked before everything else, so place it before html element.

Comment: Need not be in case if ob_start has been called. Basically, no headers or data should be sent to requesting client before invoking session or trying to create a cookie etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
if(isset($_SESSION['admin']))
```

Answer (score 1):

to check whether session exists or not you need to use `isset()` So

change

```
if($_SESSION['admin'])
```

to

```
if(isset($_SESSION['admin']))
```